# How to improve webkit image scaling performance

Tags: javascript, animation, css, webkit, jquery-animate

On a web page, I'm scaling an `<img/>` tag.

To this end, I use the css3 transform scale function linked through jquery `.animate` method (https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js). All in all, result is good on Firefox and IE9. But under webkit browser (notably chrome 21), there's a big performance cost and the animation isn't looking good.

So, I take a look at the chrome devtool timeline. And the problem is definitly caused by the repaint of the `<img/>`, the time taken to repaint the image is incredibly long.

Just so you know, we don't access dom to often (never while animating), and we use `requestAnimationFrame`. The trouble really seems to live in the algorithm used by webkit to resize images. We added css `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`, this helped a bit, but not so much.

Do anyone have a hint on this ?

Comment: D'you have any code we can see?

Comment: @arxanas If you want to see yeah, I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js

Basically though, the plugin won't cause trouble on chrome with divs, it's only with images, in Chrome. No trouble on other browser. So, this seems really tied to the image painting time in Chrome.